# try except not passing

Tags: python, try-catch, index-error, except

```
stack = []

try:
    top = stack.pop()
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Error: `IndexError: pop from empty list`

I want the try except statement to pass if the stack can't be popped, but an error is still being thrown.

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]

Comment: At least share some code it can helpful for us

Comment: This works for me as expected. Please provide a minimal reproducible example and the full traceback

Comment: Assuming `stack` is an empty list, I don't get any error for your code. I'm using python 3.8.8.

Comment: You code is fine. Perhaps check you have a) saved the file and b) are running the correct version of the code

Comment: But i think there is an empty list so there is no index here so how can it give index error.

Comment: As others have mentioned you need to post a reproducible example. However I question the need for a try/except in this case. You could just have some condition like `if stack != []: stack.pop()` or `if not stack: stack.pop()`